# Changing http request header

Tags: django, http, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I just wanted to know. Is it possible to change the http request headers sent to servers? like ip, remote address.. etc... I'm aware that I can change user-agent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a middleware that will hack or replace the request object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware